My node.JS server is not working and my page is static
I am new to web development. I built my front part via the Angular framework and it works well, my navigations are ok, my images and content too, the links to libraries like bootstrap the same.
But... I wanted to get started in the back part with node.JS but unfortunately when I launch my server with the node server.js command after building it, the page is static. All navigation no longer works, my images no longer load and I don't understand why. Could you help me ? (No errors in VS CODE)
More informations :

I have no errors in VS Code

I rebuild my file before each launch of my server

I use Angular 16 (I don't know if it's very useful but you have the info)


My server.JS file
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Configuration de la gestion des fichiers statiques

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/your-db-name')
  .then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB'))
  .catch(err => console.error('Could not connect to MongoDB', err));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './dist/three-percent/browser/index.html'));
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World from Node.js server!');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

my tsconfig.json code
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "es2020",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "server.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}

Errors on chrome :
Image of errors on chrome
I tried to launch my server several times, hoping that the application would be functional and that I could move forward with other steps such as creating a login system, retrieving information via forms, etc.

it seems as your express server delivers the index.html for all of your static assets (like images and js files).
that's why it complains, when it tries to load the js files, that the server replies with text/html MIME type.
in your server code it seems as you're delivering the static assets via:
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

I guess that there is no public directory and that's why it's not finding any asset for express static and then falling through to your '*' route which delivers the index.html.
Based on your '*' route and the default build artifact structure of Angular I think the correct path should be:
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'three-percent', 'browser')));

If you change that line i would expect it just to work.
That said, I don't think there is any reason why you should ever deliver the static Angular assets through a custom express server. For local development using ng serve is the much better approach.
ng serve
Builds and serves your application, rebuilding on file changes.

In other environments (like production, testing, etc) the static files should be delivered by a CDN or an efficient web server like nginx.
